# How to use function recursively in javascript?

Tags: jquery, recursion, onload, onkeyup

I have one form where on keyup function I am showing amount in words below that input. It's working as expected with my function. Now O have another input with 2 radio buttons. Onchange this radio buttons also I have to work my function of `ShowAmountInWords`. I am stuck here.   Suppose, I have 2 radio buttons with FD and RD. Limit for FD is 10 digits and Limit for RD is 11 digits.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#amount').on('keyup', function() {
    var amountInWrods = $('#amount').val();
    var words = changeToWord(amountInWrods); //calling that function to show amount in words
    $('#words').val(words);

  });
});

function changeToWord(amount) {
  //code to convert number to word
  return amountInWrods;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='amount' id='amount'>
<label id='words'>To show Amount in words</label>
<input type="radio" id="FD" name="tyoeofdeposit" value="FD">
<input type="radio" id="RD" name="tyoeofdeposit" value="RD">
```

I am adding my code for radio button validation inside above function.

```js
function changeToWord(amount) {
  $('input[type=radio][name=typeofDeposit]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'FD') {
      if (amount > 10) {
        return 'input less amount';
      }
    } else if (this.value == 'RD') {
      if (amount > 11) {
        return 'input less amount';
      }
    }
  });
  //code to convert number to word
  return amountInWrods;
}
```

User will input amount and it will go to onkeyup event and from here it will go to function `changetowords` in that it will check for deposit type  If user input 10 digits with FD then it will show amount in words  If user input 11 digits with FD then it will return error msg. same for RD. But problem is  when FD is selected and user will add 11 digits so it returns errormsg but now, user want to change deposit type to RD so in this case that errormsg should be gone and Amountinwords should return proper response.I am stuck here.I tried with recursion function but it shows me error of max size exceeded.

Comment: You shouldn't bind an event handler inside another event handler. Every time you do a `keyup` you're adding a duplicate `change` handler to all the radio buttons.

Comment: @Barmar any solution for this?

Comment: There's no "recursion" needed here - just call a function on a change event of the input and the same function on change event of the radio.